# IIS 5.1 session

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am hosting my website in IIS 5.1.
When i am accessing the site using localhost/xwy/Login.aspx
after entering login credential i am able to move to next page (main.aspx) of the site.
But , when I use xyz.com/xwy/login.aspx where (xyz.com is the machine name) and enter login credential  , then i am redirected back to login.aspx.After, checking Trace.axd I found in page main.aspx Session variables are not instantited i.e under Session State section no session variable is present.[image]

I am using ASP.NET 4.0 for website.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: What is in your `web.config` for authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authentication is made base on the cookies, and the cookies are set base on the **domain name**

When you change from `localhost/xwy/Login.aspx`  to `xyz.com/xwy/login.aspx` the **domain name** is change.

The reason that not work the same for both is because you probably have set the `domain` parametre on web.config. Remove it to let the cookies apply to any domain.

The place that you set the host on the web.config are:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms domain="local.com" />
</authentication>

<httpCookies domain="local.com" />
```

Comment: Thanks @Aristos for answer.In web.config I have
  <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="MyAuthenCookie" loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="60" path="/"/>
  </authentication>

Comment: ANother thing my machine name contains underscore(ex: X_W_Z).Sorry for not mentioning it before.

Comment: @NirajChoubey Then check if some extra code made the redirect. Second check if you move from one host to the other, this make fail. Check also what cookies are been set on browser.